# How can my VSTO Excel addin tell if a workbook is embedded in a word document?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, vsto, ole

I am working on an existing Excel VSTO addin that is causing problems when the user edits a workbook that is embedded in a MS Word document.  It is not a requirement that the addin function in that environment, but it is causing the embedding to malfunction, even when the customer is manipulating files unrelated to what the addin manipulates.  At minimum, I need to get it to not initialize itself for that workbook.

Some avenues I have investigated:

1. The documentation for **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook.Application** reads: *"When used without
   an object qualifier, this property returns an Application object
   that represents the Microsoft Excel application. When used with an
   object qualifier, this property returns an Application object that
   represents the creator of the specified object (you can use this
   property with an OLE Automation object to return the application of
   that object)."*  This sounds promising, however, I don't understand
   what "with an object qualifier" means in the context of C#.
2. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106231/how-to-dected-excel-was-starting-by-automation-vsto-addin-context) suggested examining the command line arguments.  However, if I open Excel standalone, then open my Word document with embedded Excel objects, Word uses the same instance for the embedding, and the command line arguments will not contain the "-embedded" flag.
3. I would love to force OLE to use a new instance of Excel (instead of reusing an existing standalone instance), but I cannot figure out how to do that either.

Since the single instance of Excel can be hosting both embedded and standalone workbooks at the same time, this information needs to be at the workbook level.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'd like to disable my addin for embedded Excel workbooks in Word documents.

Comment: Sorry, but we have not gotten back to this problem. I am, however, still interested in a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This works for telling you if the workbook is an embedded OLE object (the other answer for checking the workbook.Container did not work for me on Office 2016):
https://theofficecontext.com/2013/04/10/how-to-determine-if-an-excel-workbook-is-embedded-and-more/

```
public static class ExcelExtensionMethods
{

[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
static extern int CreateBindCtx(uint reserved, out IBindCtx ppbc);

/// <summary>
/// WORKBOOK EXTENSION METHOD
/// Checks to see if the Workbook is embeeded inside of 
/// another ActiveX Document type, sy=uch as Word or Excel.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="PobjWb"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool IsEmbedded(this Excel.Workbook PobjWb)
{
    if (PobjWb.Path == null || PobjWb.Path.Length == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            // requires using Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop;
            // and you have to manually add this to reference from here:
            // C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll
            IOleObject LobjOleObject = ((object)PobjWb) as IOleObject;
            IOleClientSite LobjPpClientSite;
            // get the client site
            LobjOleObject.GetClientSite(out LobjPpClientSite);
            // if there is one - we are embedded
            if (LobjPpClientSite != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // not embedded
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // exception
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        finally { }
    }
    else
    {
        // not embedded
        return false;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// WORKBOOK EXTENSION METHOD
/// This method return the name of the class that we
/// are embedded inside of.
/// If we are not embedded it return null.
/// If there is any exception it return null.
/// If the container cannot be accessed it returns UNKNOWN.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="PobjWb"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string EmbedClassName(this Excel.Workbook PobjWb)
{
    try
    {
        IOleObject LobjOleObject = ((object)PobjWb) as IOleObject;
        IOleClientSite LobjPpClientSite;
        // get the client site
        LobjOleObject.GetClientSite(out LobjPpClientSite);
        if (LobjPpClientSite != null)
        {
            IOleContainer LobjPpContainer;
            LobjPpClientSite.GetContainer(out LobjPpContainer);
            if (LobjPpContainer != null)
            {
                return LobjPpContainer.GetType().Name;
            }
            else
            {
                // something wrong - container is not valid
                return "UNKNOWN";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // not embedded
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        return null; // failed
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// WORKBOOK EXTENSION METHOD
/// Get the full path to the file that the workbook is embedded 
/// inside of. 
/// If we are not embeeded then this will return null.
/// If we are embedded but there are issues with the container
/// or an exception occurs, it will return null.
/// Otherwise we get the full path and filename.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="PobjWb"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string EmbedMoniker(this Excel.Workbook PobjWb)
{
    try
    {
        IOleObject LobjOleObject = ((object)PobjWb) as IOleObject;
        IOleClientSite LobjPpClientSite;
        // get the client site
        LobjOleObject.GetClientSite(out LobjPpClientSite);
        if (LobjPpClientSite != null)
        {
            IOleContainer LobjPpContainer;
            LobjPpClientSite.GetContainer(out LobjPpContainer);
            if (LobjPpContainer != null)
            {
                // get the moniker
                IMoniker LobjMoniker;
                LobjPpClientSite.GetMoniker((uint)OLEGETMONIKER.OLEGETMONIKER_FORCEASSIGN,
                                            (uint)OLEWHICHMK.OLEWHICHMK_OBJFULL,
                                            out LobjMoniker);
                if (LobjMoniker != null)
                {
                    // now pull the moniker display name
                    // this will be in the form of PATH!Context
                    string LstrDisplayName;
                    IBindCtx LobjCtx = null;
                    CreateBindCtx(0, out LobjCtx); // required (imported function)
                    LobjMoniker.GetDisplayName(LobjCtx, null, out LstrDisplayName);
                    // remove context is exists
                    if (LstrDisplayName.Contains("!"))
                    {
                        string[] LobjMonikerArray = LstrDisplayName.Split('!');
                        // return the first part - which should be the path
                        return LobjMonikerArray[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // return full display name
                        return LstrDisplayName;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // no moniker value
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // something wrong - container is not valid
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // not embedded
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print(ex.ToString());
        return null; // failed
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I will try this...but it may take a while before I get back to working on this problem.

Comment: Hi. Did the above work for you? I just tried to implement IsEmbedded as described, but no luck. I am using Office 2016

Comment: ... However I use it in the Workbook open handler where it did not work. If I use it in Close handler it works. I need to detect it during open.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with embedded Excel in Word. And the solutions have been `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` all objects in the end of each event function.

Example:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // code
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sender);
   Marshal.ReleaseComObject(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine whether the workbook is embedded into another application by checking the `Workbook.Container` property. It will contain the Word `Document` object that contains the embedded workbook if a workbook is embedded. Otherwise calling the property will throw an exception so make sure to wrap the check into a try-catch block:

```
public bool IsEmbedded(Workbook workbook)
{
    try
    {
        // via the container you get a handle to the parent Word document object
        var container = workbook.Container;
        return true;
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        if (ex.ErrorCode == -2146822566)
        {
            // Exception message is: 
            // "This property is only available if the document is an OLE object."   
            return false;
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

---

<s>It may be possible to rely on the `Workbook.Path` or `Workbook.Name` property.</s>

For me I get the following results when I check these properties for an embedded Excel workbook:

```
// this is empty for an embedded workbook
Application.Workbooks[1].Path; 

// this contains the string "Worksheet in <document name>.docx"
Application.Workbooks[1].Name;
```

Comment: The call **workbook.Container** doesn't work for me.  It always throws the exception -2146822566  (0x800A165A) whether the workbook is a standalone excel application or a workbook embedded in Word.  What might be different about my system?  I'm using Office 2016.

Comment: Maybe the way the workbook is embedded differs? Just guessing though... Could you share a sample document?

Comment: I am working two scenarios: (1) run Excel and make a blank worksheet. (2) Run Word, on the "Insert" ribbon select "Object...", select "Create New" and "Microsoft Excel Worksheet".  Then select the newly-created Excel worksheet.  Note that I'm getting a different error code than you documented.  I read somewhere that Workbook.Container is not available in "Partially Trusted Assemblies".  I'm trying to research if this might be a contributing factor.